# Why is this haskell function giving me a parse error?

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am trying to say if the desired location in the field is 1 return true otherwise return false. Why is this code not working?

```
fireShot :: Coordinate -> Field -> Bool
fireShot coord Shipfield
 | nth ( fst(coord)((nth snd(coord)) ShipField) == 1 = True
 | otherwise                                         = False
```

Comment: Parentheses don't look balanced: 5 left, 4 right.

Comment: The brackets in the guard are not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brackets in the guard are not balanced, you open *five* brackets, and you close *four* brackets. Furthermore variables start with a lowercase, so it should (probably) be `shipfield`, not <s>`Shipfield`</s>.

I think it might be better to use pattern matching to obtain the first and second coordinate, since this will make the code more clean. You furthermore do not need guards to return `True` and `False`. You can replace the function with:

```
fireShot :: Coordinate -> Field -> Bool
fireShot (x,y) shipfield = nth x (nth y shipfield) == 1
```